# Start/Stop Music playing when power is supplied via the USB cable

Tags: usb, charging, music, automotive-head-unit

I'd like to use an old(er) Android phone as a Music Player left always connected in my car. I have an ignition controlled USB socket in the car, and would also connect the 3.5mm jack to the Aux In of the car. Is there a way to set a Music Player (e.g. MediaMonkey) to 'continue' playing when power is supplied to the USB charging cable, and then stop when power is disconnected?
The reason I'd like to do this is because the Infotainment system in my car (Mazda CX-5) is horribly slow to start up, and music on USB memory stick or played over Bluetooth from my phone takes 2-3 minutes to start up (whereas music connected via the Aux-In starts up almost immediately). I have Android Auto and that's even worse!
I've searched this (and other) forums without finding anything that does this simply.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that there is a music player that directly can start playing when USB is connected. But USB charging starts/stops is a global event which can be received by any app, therefore apps like tasker could be used to listen for this event and then send an command/intent to MediaMonkey to continue playing. Unfortunately MediaMonkey knowledgebase on that topic seems to be non-public. You could also create a post on for this topic https://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm a member over on media monkey, so I'll have alook around/ask on there.

Answer (score 0):

## Bixby Routines

If you have a newish Samsung device with bixby routines (found in advanced settings) then you can create a routine that triggers when the device begins charging that can send the OS's "play music" command, open specific apps, and call actions that those app registered with android. You might need to open the app, and then send the OS's "play music" command.

## Automation apps

If you don't have a Samsung device, then there are apps that can likely solve your problem. An app called [ITTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt) is a well known automation app that may solve your problem. It can detect when your device begins charging, and it can do one of three things: open an app, send the OS's "play music" command, or integrate with specific services, like Spotify, and use reliable platform specific commands such as playing a shuffled playlist.

If ITTT doesn't work, other automation apps may.

Comment: Thanks Grant, will have a play with Bixby as well. I'm making some progress now with Tasker, but it's great to have alternatives!